# PreUpdate event listener crashes the site

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to build a preUpdate, I was doing it with a postUpdate but I didn't contemplate the fact that I was changing whenever an edit of that entity was being made, no matter the field... so I read I should use preUpdate instead...

This is my preUpdate Listener:

```
namespace Prizes\PrizesBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Prizes\PrizesBundle\Entity\Prize;
use Prizes\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatalogHasPrize as CHP;

/**
 * Description of DeactivatePrizesInCatalog
 *
 * @author Victoria Noguera
 * Desactiva premios en catalogos cuando se desactiven en el prize central.
 */
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class DeactivatePrizesInCatalog {
/**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
       $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntity

Manager();
    if ($entity instanceof Prize) {
        if ($args->hasChangedField('status')) {
            $status_new = $args->getNewValue('status');
            if ($status_new->getName() == "Inactive") {
                $statusinactive = $entityManager->getRepository('AppStatusBundle:Status')->find(8);
                $q = $entityManager->createQuery("UPDATE CatalogBundle:CatalogHasPrize c SET c.status = :statusid WHERE c.status = 7 AND c.prize = :prizeid")
                        ->setParameters(array('statusid' => $statusinactive, 'prizeid' => $entity->getId()));
                $rs = $q->getResult();
            } else if ($status_new->getName() == "Active") {
                $statusinactive = $entityManager->getRepository('AppStatusBundle:Status')->find(7);
                $q = $entityManager->createQuery("UPDATE CatalogBundle:CatalogHasPrize c SET c.status = :statusid WHERE c.status = 8 AND c.prize = :prizeid")
                        ->setParameters(array('statusid' => $statusinactive, 'prizeid' => $entity->getId()));
                $rs = $q->getResult();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

and this is the way i'm doing it on the config.yml file (I just read it goes in a services.yml, but i'll change it later)

```
services:
    preupdate.listener:
        class: Prizes\PrizesBundle\EventListener\DeactivatePrizesInCatalog
        tags: 
             - { name: doctrine.event_listener , event: preUpdate }
```

however, when I do this, my project goes from fully functional to 503 service unavailable. Even if I just write `public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) { }` it crashes, I'm assuming a configuration issue, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I'd appreciate any help offered. Thank you

Comment: Which error is in the errorlog?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding mapping information to your listener which itself is not an entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
```

and ...

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
```

... must not be in your listener class.

Those annotations can be used in an entity if the entity itself contains i.e. the prePersist methods.

Comment: what do symfony's logfiles say `app\logs\dev.log` ... if you can't find something in there inspect php and webserver logfiles. Leaving away those unneeded annotations is a first step :) important ... did you clear your cache?

Comment: Not the symfony logfiles, the apache or nginx logfiles. They will say exactly what the problem is. 503 error looks like serverissue instead of sf issue

Comment: Apache Log File doesn't have anything related to that project.

Comment: what happens if you run `php -l` against your listener file? ... just to clarify .. if you comment the listener configuration with `#` ( or remove it temporarily ) ... and clear your cache ... your site works flawlessly?

Comment: Hi, Yes if I comment the listener configurations it works. It works on my local server just fine with the current configuration. The Dev Log doesn't have anything and neither does the Prod Log. Php -l says no syntax errors were detected

Comment: and Yes, i've cleared the cache numberous times, still not working

Comment: Okay, Symfony seems unable to generate new cache. I must say, I'm using Windows and works perfectly, maybe it has something to do with case. The Server uses Ubuntu, it has to be something with the configuration